# Saving Outlook Mailitem with embedded image as part of the mail

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, cpu-word

For some reason, saving an Outlook MailItem that has an embedded image causes the PDF file to lose the embedded image instead of saving the image alongside the mail item. It sees the image as an attachment instead of being apart of the actual mail itself. Whats weird though, is that this only happens when saving to PDF, if I try to save the MailItem to .RTF, the image is not lost.

This is how I save a mailitem:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
doc.SaveAs(PDFpath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

And I have an if-statement that ensures that the embedded image isn't saved as an attachment:

```
if (!mailItem.HTMLBody.Contains(aFileName))
{
  a.SaveAsFile(attachmentPath);
  contentEditor.AddDocumentAttachment(attachmentPath, aFileName);
  contentEditor.Save(PDFpath);
}
```

The content editor stuff here is to bind the attachments to the saved PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveAs` takes `OlSaveAsType` format as the second parameter, not `WdSaveFormat`.

PDF format is not supported by `OlSaveAsType`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olsaveastype?view=outlook-pia

You can try to save in the MHTML format (`OlSaveAsType.olMHTML`), open the file in Word using Word Object Model, and save it as PDF.

Comment: Well I'm not using the Outlook SaveAs, I'm using the Word Interop SaveAs, which takes the WdSaveFormat parameter. It works fine for converting the document that has only text, but if an image is present, it will not be shown. Is it really because I can only use the Outlook SaveAs and not the Word interop?